# Enabling Apps in admin center is unavailable. How to change settings?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to enable Apps on my development tenant but the settings are unavailable.

[image]

I'm not sure why, but I've seen it at some colleagues as well.
How can I enable App sideloading to try out development?

Comment: If you don't currently have an Office 365 account, you can sign up for the [Office 365 Developer program](https://dev.office.com/devprogram) to get a free one-year Office 365 Developer Tenant. This account can only be used for testing purposes.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I very much have an Office 365 developer account. It’s just that these settings are unavailable and I don’t know why. If it helps, my tenant name is ns365.sharepoint.com. Thanks.

Comment: Office 365 tenants are _always_ in the form _TenantString_.onmicrosoft.com - ns365.sharepoint.com is not an Office 365 tenant. How did you get to the screen you took the screenshot from?

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT ns365.onmicrosoft.com is my tenant name, .sharepoint.com indeed the sharepoint domain. I got the screenshot by going to https://admin.microsoft.com > Settings > Services & add-ins > Microsoft Teams

Comment: @Nsevens, we've identified the problem but we're not sure why it's happening. Where/how did you get your version of Office? It's showing up as a SKU ("E3 Developer" I think) that Teams doesn't support - not because we don't want to, but because we don't know about it.

Comment: By any chance is this a developer tenant that you renewed? It only became possible recently to renew a developer tenant so it may be a new SKU.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT it's possible but I'm not sure. I've seen the same issue with lots of my colleagues. SKU is "Office365 Enterprise E3 Developer MSDN", which I received together with my MSDN license.

Comment: @Nsevens- This has been fixed. Could you please try it again at your end and let us know if you are still facing this issue?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT indeed, it's fixed. I have all the settings now - as do my colleagues. Thanks!